# layout and flex order in angular material

Tags: angular-material

I have a container that is a row if screen size is greater than "sm" in angular material

```
 <div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" layout-margin="20px"  >
 <div id="div1" flex="80">
 </div>
  <div id="div2" flex="20">
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

When it turns to a column, I need my `div2` stacked onto top of div1 but as the natural order is, divs on the left are stacked over divs on right.

How can I change this and have the div on right on the top of `div1` or any other div for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex-order` and `flex-order-gt-sm` option to get the desired result. 
http://codepen.io/next1/pen/EKXedG

For more info check the offical doc [Material Layout](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children)